# rails4 condition with mixed parent and child attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.2

The following where condition

```
Contractor.includes(:contractorusers).where(['building_id = ? AND contractorusers.user_id = ?', 21, 72]).all
```

generates a complaint, that according to the database `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "contractorusers"` notwithstanding the database does have that defined

```
  create_table "contractorusers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "contractor_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
```

Thus the syntax clearly needs fixing. How?

Answer (score 0):

Query you have written will not work as includes will first call on parent to get contract related to id and then will search for contractorusers with array of ids return by parent query.

Try this:

```
Contractor.joins(:contractorusers).where("building_id = ? AND contractorusers.user_id = ?", 21, 72)
```